# Using RegEx to Count the Length of the String in a Matched Pattern

Tags: php, regex

I've been trying to resolve this all day.

**Here are the requirements:**
  - I want to match strings that optionally starts with " _ "
  - Should then continue with one or more case-insensitive alphabet
  - Should then contain an optional " _ " or " - " followed by case-insensitive alphanumeric characters (This step should match at lease once).
  - Then it may optionally end with " _ "

**The above requirements are not a problem 'cos I achieved that with:**

```
/_?[A-Za-z]([-_]?[A-Za-z0-9])+_?/
```

**The above RegEx matches:**

- user_
- *usEr-nAme*
- uSer_naMe-Two_
- _Userna-Me_tHree-and-four

**THE PROBLEM**
How do I make it match only 6 to 25 characters?

**I Tried**

```
/(_?[A-Za-z]([-_]?[A-Za-z0-9])+_?){6,25}/
```

but it still matches string less than 6 like Use-r

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put a lookahead assertion at the start:

```
(?=^.{6,25}$)_?[A-Za-z]([-_]?[A-Za-z0-9])+_?
```

[Demo here](https://regex101.com/r/oJ6vL6/4).

Comment: I guess you want: `(?=.{6,25}$)`?

Comment: and optional also `^` at the start or `\b`, not exactly sure what OP wants.

Comment: Thank you! Just what I needed!